# Nginx proxy depending on user

Tags: nginx, proxy

I need to use different backend depending on user. I have a couple of servers connected to main server using VPN tunnels. Users should login to the main server and the main server should use different backend depending on user name. I’m sure that it may be done by nginx.

Here is the details:
—server flow— (already implemented)
Backend server connects to the main server via OpenVPN
OpenVPN on the main server configured to execute script on connection event
This script just requests backend for the unique ID and puts ID and IP address to the database.
Also the database contains user and backend ID relations table
—user flow— (need to implement, here is just an idea)
User comes to the main server via https
Enters login and password
Script on the main server finds in the database server ID related to this user and IP address
Script sets something like cookie with session id
At the next request from the user nginx (using session id and information about backend IP) acts like a proxy between backend and the user

Any ideas how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is through sticky sessions and it's not available from Nginx free edition, see [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/832790/sticky-sessions-with-nginx-proxy/839999#839999).

You can also use specific routes for each kind of user but it would be insecure.

The last option I can think of is using the module Lua Resty for Nginx, see https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md